# Query for filter permission

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I need some help for a MySQL query. 
A student can get permissions to borrow a book from one of a group he belong or from an individual permission. Also the books are related to groups.

I would like to get the all the books, in a perfoming way, that a student can get according to his permissions or groups permission. Also how can I filter from one or severals groupID?

Note that if a book is not in a permission table, it means it is available for everybody

Here's a sample of the schema of the database.

```
--table book--
bookID     name      

--table group--
groupdID     name

-- table student --
studID    name

-- table group_book --
bookID     groupID

-- table student_group--
groupdID     studID

-- table student_book_permission --
bookID     studID

-- table group_book_permission --
bookID     groupID
```

Thanks for yout help and your time

Comment: What's the difference between group_book and group_book_permission tables? How does the former impact the permissions?

Comment: It does not, it is just in an informative way, in order to filter them by group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select s.studid, s.name, b.bookid, b.name
from student s
left join student_book_permission sbp on s.studid=sbp.studid
left join book b on sbp.bookid=b.bookid
union distinct
select s.studid, s.name, b.bookid, b.name
where s.studid=?
from student s
left join student_group sg on s.studid=sg.studid
left join group_book_permission gbp on sg.groupid=gbp.groupid
left join book b on gbp.bookid=b.bookid
where s.studid=?
```

The list of books a student has access to is produced by a union of 2 queries. The top query gets the list of books the student has permission to on individual basis. The bottom query lists the books based on group permissions. Union distinct ensures that a book is only shown once in the list.

Comment: Tanks a lot, but I also need to get books where all permissions are null (meaning everybody has access to it)

Comment: Add another select then with union that select the books with null permissions (left join with a combination of is null)